# Complex Django search engine

Tags: django, django-filter

I want my Django search engine to be able to handle typos on the title of the item I would display. For example if the user does the search 'stacoverflow' I would search for 'stackoverflow'. I would then apply other filters I already have and could display the results.

What would be the best way to do this and how could I do it? Consider some specific strings and then change their values, how?

My Models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=None, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    # ...
```

My views:

```
def is_valid_queryparam(param):
    return param != '' and param is not None


def FilterView(request):
    qs = Product.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    title_contains_query = request.GET.get('title_contains')
    id_exact_query = request.GET.get('title_exact')
    title_or_author_query = request.GET.get('title_or_author')
    view_count_min = request.GET.get('view_count_min')
    view_count_max = request.GET.get('view_count_max')
    date_min = request.GET.get('date_min')
    date_max = request.GET.get('date_max')
    category = request.GET.get('category')

    if is_valid_queryparam(title_contains_query):
        qs = qs.filter(title__icontains=title_contains_query)

    elif is_valid_queryparam(id_exact_query):
        qs = qs.filter(id=id_exact_query)

    elif is_valid_queryparam(title_or_author_query):
        qs = qs.filter(Q(title__icontains=title_or_author_query) | Q(author__username__icontains=title_or_author_query)).distinct()

    #...

    if is_valid_queryparam(category) and category != 'Choose...':
        qs = qs.filter(category__name=category)

    context = {
        'queryset': qs,
        'categories': categories
    }

    return render(request, 'search/filter_form.html', context)
```

My templates:

```
<form method="GET" action=".">
    <div>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Title contains..." name="title_contains">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="search" placeholder="ID exact..." name="id_exact"/>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Title or author..." name="title_or_author"/>
    </div>

...

    <div>
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select id="category" name="category">
            <option selected>Choose...</option>
            {% for category in categories %}
                <option value="{{ category }}">{{ category }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

<div>
    <ul>
        {% for product in queryset %}
        <li>
            {{ product.title }}
            <span>Author: {{ product.author.name }}</span>
            <span>Category: {{ product.category }}</span>
...
        </li>
        <hr />
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thik you can use [Trigams](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#trigram-similarity) to search for similar words. See also others [search functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/).

Comment: Would I have to use PostgreSQL for Triagams?

Comment: Yes, but you could look for similar functions in the DB engine you are using.

Comment: Isn't there any other way you can think of?

Comment: Maybe django-elasticsearch could work.